# Email notification when any cell in specific column is changed

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I have a Google Sheet in which I would like to get an email notification when any cell changes in a specific column.
I am new to scripting so it is mind blowing, I have no idea on how to do this and would appreciate any assistance on this.

Column U2:U

---

**Updated script**

This works when I manually edit any cell in column U. However I would like to have an formula/arrayformula in this column but when I do this I stop receiving email notifications.

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
if (e.range.columnStart != 21 ) return; 
GmailApp.sendEmail("email.address@gmail.com","Subject", "New Name Added - See Cell U" + e.range.rowStart + " Sheet Name") 
}
```

Comment: Hi. There are two issues. #1) You want to get an email when any cell changes in column V2:V; there are many precedents and I do understand it is hard to know where to start/how to find them. I'm sure we can/will help. #2) _I am new to script so have no idea where to start_. With respect, that is an excuse, not a problem. You need to prioritise development of skills. As a starting point, @Rubén gave a link to the Guide to Apps Script, and I'd also recommend the Google [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials).

Comment: You must have also set an installable trigger (`onEdit` (or possibly an `OnChange` with this script) - that's okay if the script is doing what you want it to do. Regarding _I would like to have an formula/arrayformula in this column but when I do this I stop receiving email notifications_, would you please explain the exact problem that you are having. But note that [An installable edit trigger runs when `a user modifies a value in a spreadsheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). The script will not execute because a formula value changes.

Answer (score 1):

You want to send an email when a value chnages in Column U2:U. Your `onEdit` script works but... You have formula/arrayformula in Column U and the script is not being triggered by changes in those values.

An `onEdit` script is on triggered **when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet**. Changes due to formula do **not** trigger the script.

**Workaround**

An option is to use a time-driven trigger.

The challenge is to establish whether a value in Column U has changed since the last time the script was run. The solution is to make a copy of the values in Column U and to compare these against the actual values when the script is executed.

The solution consists of two scripts:

- `function duplicaterange()`:

  - **run once only** - no trigger.
  - creates the initial reference copy of the values in Column U.
  - for sake of simplicity, the script uses Column V for the reference data. You can change this to a different column/sheet.
- `function sendemail()`

  - script must be installed as a `time-driven trigger`; the frequency is at your option.
  - compares the current/actual values of cells in Column U against the reference copy.
  - where the current/actual value <> reference copy, then an email is sent.
  - regardless of whether any/many emails are sent, the last step in this script is to update the reference copy of the values in Column U. This, the reference copy is always up-to-date.

---

```
function duplicaterange(){

  // needs to be run ONLY ONCE to initiate a reference range

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  
  // parameters to get a data range
  var datafirstrow = 2;
  var dataCol = 21; // Column U = 21
  // get the last row
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row = "+LR);
  if (LR <= datafirstrow){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no data")
    return;
  }
  
  // get range for column U
  var sourcerange = sheet.getRange(datafirstrow, dataCol, LR-datafirstrow+1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range = "+sourcerange.getA1Notation())
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
  
  // create target row (assume column V)
  var targetrange = sheet.getRange(datafirstrow, dataCol+1, LR-datafirstrow+1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetrange.getA1Notation());
  
  // copy source to target
  targetrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return;
  
}
```

---

```
function sendemail(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  
  // parameters to get a data range
  var datafirstrow = 2;
  var dataColU = 21; // Column U = 21
  var dataColTarget = 22; // Column V = 22
  
  // get the last row
  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row = "+LR)
  if (LR <= datafirstrow){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no data")
    return;
  }
  
  // get range for column U
  var sourcerange = sheet.getRange(datafirstrow, dataColU, LR-datafirstrow+1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the range = "+sourcerange.getA1Notation())
  var sourcevalues = sourcerange.getValues();
  
  // get the target range (assume column V)
  var targetrange = sheet.getRange(datafirstrow, dataColTarget, LR-datafirstrow+1)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetrange.getA1Notation())
  var targetvalues = targetrange.getValues();

  // calculate the number of rows of data
  var numrows = LR-datafirstrow+1;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the number of rows = "+numrows)
 
  for (var i=0;i<numrows;i++){
    if (sourcevalues[i][0] != targetvalues[i][0]){
      // values do not match, so Column U has changed
      // so send email
      var rownumber = i+datafirstrow;
      //GmailApp.sendEmail("email.address@gmail.com","Subject", "New Name Added - See Cell U" + rownumber + " Sheet Name") 
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", send an email for row number "+rownumber);
     }
  }
  
 
  // update the revised source data to target range
  targetrange.setValues(sourcevalues);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
  return;

}
```