# How can I get email notifications for changed cells, including what changed and context from some nearby cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I would like to receive help in modifying the scripts in [Email notification when any cell in specific column is changed](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/149137/email-notification-when-any-cell-in-specific-column-is-changed).

Based on previous code, how can I make the email content include not only the address of the changed cell, but also what is written in it and add data from other columns? For example, in an email I would like to see that Mr. Smith (column A with the title - person), who works as IT Support (column B with the title - position in the company) has changed his status to available (column C with the title - status)

The email would look something like this: Mr. Smith (IT Support), has changed the status to available.

Can you suggest some code?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Please show how you have tried adapting the code to your specific needs. Please remember that Web Applications SE is about using web apps, not about programming, so questions on this should be focused on Google Sheets and Google Apps Script features rather than on asking for suggestions on some code. If you have not done so yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.