# Modification of the Google Sheet script for email notifications

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I use the code from this answer in my file: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/149424/316384

Can someone help me modify it so that the script sends an email when the value changes to the one I set?
For example, if the cell value changes from "Orange" to "Blue", I would like to receive an email notification, and if "Blue" changes back to "Orange", I do not want notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

There, you will learn that Google Apps Script uses JavaScript as a programming language and how to read and write spreadsheets.
If you are new to programming and JavaScript, besides the resources pointed out by Google, you might find the JavaScript course offered by FreeCodeCamp. One of the advanges of this course, besides being free, it's that it's focused on JavaScript, it doesn't require to know HTML, CSS to start with the course, among other things.

Note: I'm just a Google apps and FreeCodeMember user.

Then read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers.

There, you will learn about simple triggers in Google Apps Script. In this case, the one that might be helpful is onEdit. Please note that this trigger is triggered only by changes done using the Google Sheets user interface. If the cell value changes due to an add-on or third party tool the onEdit function will not be triggered.